# Filling a dynamic array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a struct with pointers to floats that i want to turn into an array of an indeterminate size. At the beginning of my program I want to declare a few of these structs and turn them into different sized arrays, like this:

```
struct _arr {
   float * a;
}
```

...

```
_arr x;
x.a = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float)*31);
x.a = { 6,
        1, 1, 1, 0     , 0     ,
        1, 0, 1, 0     , 0.0625,
        1, 1, 0, 0.0625, 0     ,
        1, 0, 1, 0     , 0.0625,
        1, 0, 0, 0.0625, 0.0625,
        1, 1, 0, 0.0625, 0
      };
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, does anyone have any suggestions get the values into the array besides adding in each value in individually (such as a[0] = 6;)?

Comment: Can you store an `std::vector<float>` instead of a pointer?

Comment: If you know the contents at compile time, why do you need a dynamic array?

Comment: @PhilippMatthiasSchäfer they could need different instances to hold arrays of different sizes, with different values.

Comment: Yes, im using different instances of different sizes.

Comment: If I use a vector wont it be slower to retrieve the values than if I use an array?

Comment: Even if it will be slower, are you sure you need to increase performance there? You should not optimize before performance problems arise, and `std::vector` is much easier to use.

Comment: *"Filling a dynamic array C++"* - *"`x.a = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float)*31);`"* - Something doesn't match here.

Comment: Accessing a vector is very unlikely to be slower than accessing a  dynamically allocated array.

Answer (score 3):

This could be simplified by storing a `std::vector<float>`:

```
#include <vector>

struct arr_ {
   std::vector<float> a;
};
```

In C++11, the initialization is trivial:

```
arr_ x{ {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f} };
```

Unfortunately, there is no trivial way to perform such an initialization in C++03. One option would be to initialize from a temporary fixed size array:

```
float farray_[5] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f};
arr_ x{ std::vector<float>(farray_, farray_+5)};
```

Comment: +1 though C++11 only, because of uniform initialization. What would be the recommended way without C++11?

Comment: To be accurate `_arr` is perfectly fine (I still wouldn't recommend it, of course), but `_Arr` wouldn't be. It's double underscores and leading underscores followed by upper-case letters.

Comment: @Andre I can't think of a C++03 solution that doesn't involve setting the elements one by one, or copying the elements of a fixed size array into the vector.

Comment: By the way, you're using `double` literals instead of `float`s. Of course this is just fine and the compiler will take care of it, but if not caring about a correctly typed literal, there isn't any need for a floating-point literal in the first place and you could just leave away the dot anyway.

Comment: @ChristianRau thanks for the comments. These details are important here, since this is meant to be educational. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize an `array` on the `stack` and then copy/`memcpy` to your dynamic memory. But using `vector` as suggested would be the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

x.a is a pointer and when you  change x.a = xx you change the address

try this code:

x.a = **new** float( 6,
        1, 1, 1, 0     , 0     ,
        1, 0, 1, 0     , 0.0625,
        1, 1, 0, 0.0625, 0     ,
        1, 0, 1, 0     , 0.0625,
        1, 0, 0, 0.0625, 0.0625,
        1, 1, 0, 0.0625, 0
      ) ;

Comment: yep  in vs2010 and i have a warning

Comment: Is there a way I can work with x.a = new float[31] ? Doing that produces an empty array of 31 size, but is there a trivial way to fill that array up?